# How to pass class scope instead of newly created object scope in javascript es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fullcalendar, es6-modules, es6-class

I have a class called `pop` which creates pop-up dialogs on a calendar created by [fullcalendar][1]

```
export default class pop {
  calendar = null;

  setCalendar() {
    this.calendar = new Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'), {
      eventSourceSuccess: setMinMaxSlotTime,
    }
  };

  setMinMaxSlotTime(eventArray) {
    this.calendar.setOption('slotMaxTime', maxTime + ':59:59');
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because when eventSourceSuccess is triggered, `this` refers to `Calendar` instead of `pop`, so `this.calendar` is undefined in the `setMinMaxSlotTime` function. Is there a way to tell the `setMinMaxSlotTime` to use the `calendar` class variable instead of the `Calendar` variable (which does not exist)?

**NOTE:** I was able to make some kind of workaround as follows, first by aliasing `that` to `this` and then passing the `calendar` object to the function, but I feel there's a much better way.

```
  setCalendar() {
    const that = this;

    this.calendar = new Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'), {
      eventSourceSuccess(eventArray) { that.setMinMaxSlotTime(eventArray, that.calendar); },
    }
  }

  setMinMaxSlotTime(eventArray, calendar) {
    calendar.setOption('slotMaxTime', maxTime + ':59:59');
  }


  [1]: https://fullcalendar.io/
```

Comment: Slight correction: `eventSourceSuccess:   this.setMinMaxSlotTime.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the method as a [class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) so that the `this` context is automatically bound and cannot be changed.

```js
setMinMaxSlotTime = (eventArray) => {
    this.calendar.setOption('slotMaxTime', maxTime + ':59:59');
}
```

Alternatively, you could bind the `this` value manually, like so:

```js
this.setMinMaxSlotTime.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution:

```
export default class pop {
  calendar = null;
  scope=this;
  setCalendar() {
    scope.calendar = new Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'), {
      eventSourceSuccess: setMinMaxSlotTime,
    })
  };

  setMinMaxSlotTime(eventArray) {
    scope.calendar.setOption('slotMaxTime', maxTime + ':59:59');
  }
}
```

Better solution: use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) or [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call)

Comment: this doesn't quite work as written because `scope.calendar` doesn't exist in `setCalendar` or in `setMinMaxSlotTime`. Maybe `this.scope.calendar`